I'm unable to run specific terminal commands from a Java program in Eclipse
Using ProcessBuilder in JAVA I am not able to clear the previous console but it but it work on the compiler on my phone , don't know why?
NOTE:
my compiler on my phone is Jvdroid
package dsadsa;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class javaProgram5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    // Main loop to process employee details
    int slipNo = 0;
    char processMore = 'Y'; // Initialize to 'Y' to enter the loop
    
    while (Character.toUpperCase(processMore) == 'Y') {
        clearConsole(); // Clear the console before each new input
        
        // Input employee details
        System.out.println("Slip No.: " + slipNo);
        System.out.println("EMELITO TOLENTINO MAN POWER, INC.");
        System.out.println("General Santos City");
        System.out.print("Employee's Name: ");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        
        // Gender input with validation and immediate display
        String genderFull = "";
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Gender [M/F]: ");
            String genderInput = scanner.nextLine().toUpperCase();
            
            // Move cursor to the right and display the gender
            System.out.print("\033[1A");
            System.out.print("\033[50C");
            
            if (genderInput.equals("M")) {
                genderFull = "Male";
                System.out.println(genderFull);
                break;
            } else if (genderInput.equals("F")) {
                genderFull = "Female";
                System.out.println(genderFull);
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Please enter 'M' for Male or 'F' for      Female.");
            }
        }
        
        System.out.print("Age: ");
        int age = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine(); // Consume newline
        
        System.out.print("Address: ");
        String address = scanner.nextLine();
        
        // Position Code input with options and immediate display
        String positionCode = "";
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Position Codes [1,2,3]: ");
            int positionCodeInput = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.print("\033[1A");
            System.out.print("\033[50C");
            
            switch (positionCodeInput) {
                case 1:
                    positionCode = "Carpenter";
                    System.out.println(positionCode);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    positionCode = "Masonry";
                    System.out.println(positionCode);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    positionCode = "Steelman";
                    System.out.println(positionCode);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("\nInvalid input. Please enter 1, 2, or 3.");
                    continue; // Prompt again
            }
            break; // Exit loop if a valid code is entered
        }
        
        System.out.print("No. of Days Worked: ");
        int daysWorked = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Rate/Day: ");
        double ratePerDay = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Overtime Pay: ");
        double overtimePay = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Deduction: ");
        double deduction = scanner.nextDouble();
        scanner.nextLine(); // Consume newline
        
        // Calculate Gross and Net Pay
        double grossPay = (daysWorked * ratePerDay) + overtimePay;
        double netPay = grossPay - deduction;
        
        // Display Pay Slip in the layout
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("      ------Pay Slip------   ");
        System.out.println("Name: " + name + "    Gender: " + genderFull + "    Age: " + age + "    Address: " + address);
        System.out.printf("Position: %s     Gross Pay: ₱%.2f     Net Pay: ₱%.2f\n", positionCode, grossPay, netPay);
        
        // Ask if the user wants to process another payslip
        slipNo++;
        System.out.print("Do you want to process another payslip? (Y/N): ");
        processMore = scanner.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0); // Store the input directly
        
        }
    scanner.close(); // Close scanner
    }

// Method to clear the console
public static void clearConsole() {
    try {
        if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows")) {
            new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
        } else {
            new ProcessBuilder("clear").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
        }
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }

it works on the compilier on my phone can someone teach me how to make it work in eclipse?
Sorry for my grammar and spelling?
this is not part of the question this is just so i can post this question**
dont mind this
In this example, the System.getProperty("os.name") method is used to get the name of the operating system. Then, an if-else statement is used to execute the corresponding command to clear the console based on the operating system.
If the operating system is Windows, the cls command is executed.
If the operating system is Mac or Linux, the clear command is executed.
If the operating system is neither Windows, Mac, nor Linux, a message is printed indicating that the operating system is unsupported.
By using platform-specific commands, you can ensure that your Java program can clear the console on different operating systems.

If you are running this in Eclipse you are using the Eclipse console which is not the same as the OS terminal. The Eclipse console does not support being cleared - the console is intended just for debugging runs of your code so clearing it and loosing the output would not be a good thing.

I opened a Command Prompt and ran you code and it clears the console.
